# "Worst possibly imaginable thing" : Is this gramatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

"Worst possibly imaginable thing"- my teacher kept repeating this over and over. It somehow doesn't sound good to me. Is it just me or is it really incorrect? If yes, I seek an explanation as to why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noun “thing” needs a determiner:

1 "**The** worst possibly imaginable thing"- **possibly** is an adverb  modifying “**imaginable**” – thus = "**The** worst {**possibly imaginable**} thing" = (i) The worst thing that a person might or might not be able to imagine. (ii) The worst thing, but one that we think might be unimaginable.

… and that is a strange idea. A “*possibly imaginable*” thing might be the graph of y = 1/(1-x): it is possible to imagine (= form a picture of in your mind of) this graph, but not everyone can imagine it.

2 “The worst **possible** imaginable thing"- This is the commoner form.
"**The** {worst **possible**} imaginable thing"- {worst **possible**} is adjectival phrase and modifies “thing”. This is idiomatic. = (i) The worst possible thing that you can imagine, i.e. you cannot imagine anything worse.

> my teacher kept repeating this over and over. … If yes, I seek an explanation as to why.

I could possibly imagine that it is a joke. A phrase that amuses him.